# how to specify chromedriver path in properties file

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, maven-archetype

I generated selenium project's structure using [ru.stqa.selenium](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.stqa.selenium/webdriver-testng-archetype/4.2). Also modified the setup to use chrome properties.
I would like to specify chromedriver path in the properties file. Can someone point out what would be the right way for mentioning chromedriver path.
Currently I am using following in properties file --

```
browserName=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/mphome/devspace/testAutomation/webdriver/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your properties file like below `<key,value>` pair:

```
browserName=chrome
Path=/Users/mphome/devspace/testAutomation/webdriver/chromedriver
```

Initialize the java properties object and get the chromedriver path. 
For example:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("PATH/TO/Properties File"));
String chromeDriverPath = prop.getProperty("Path");
```

Finally set the chromedriver path using `System.setProperty()` method -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
```

Then for initializing the chromedriver you can use the below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```